# Attach a PDF/Doc file With my mail

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, email, email-attachments

I have Generated pdf Files from online. While seeing the pdf, i want to send that pdf via mail with that pdf attached automatically. I used lot of codes but everything works fine for single pdf.can any one help me .

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What errors did you experience?

Comment: " I used lot of codes but everything works fine for single pdf.can any one help me ." If it works fine what help do you need ?

Comment: @sosborn . I have no erro. In iphone while seeing the photo you can send the photo via mail that photo will be attached automatically. like that i want to send the pdf file

Comment: Get the file name from the link which you are seeing and bind it to @Gypsa coding in that place where to specify the file name and send it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){      

    MFMailComposeViewController *mail=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [mail setSubject:@"Email with attached pdf"];   
    NSString *newFilePath = @"get path where the pdf reside";

    NSData * pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:newFilePath];
[mail addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"yourpdfname.pdf"];
    NSString * body = @"";
    [mail setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
    [mail release];         
}
else
{
    //NSLog(@"Message cannot be sent");
}
```

Comment: Now the problem is my filename will have to change depending upon the pdf i am seeing.But it comes the same name for all.

Comment: Then change the name dynamically. Gypsa was just giving you sample code - it is up to you to put the work in to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Gypsa 
Here is the swift code

```
func composeMail(){        
        if(MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()){

            var mail:MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self

            mail.setSubject("Email with attached pdf")

            //file name "attatchment.pdf" in project bundle
            var newFilePath:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("attatchment", ofType: "pdf")!

            var pdfData:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: newFilePath as String)!
            mail.addAttachmentData(pdfData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "attatchment.pdf")

            var body:NSString = ""
            mail.setMessageBody(body as String, isHTML: false)
            self.presentViewController(mail, animated: true) { () -> Void in

            }

        }else{

            println("Message cannot be sent")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!)
    {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

mime type is change for pdf so use this mime type it worksfine for me

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);
```

Then at some point in the future you'll need to pass that pdfData to the MFMailComposeViewController.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[vc setSubject:@"my pdf"];
[vc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"image/pdf" fileName:@"SomeFile.pdf"];
```

Comment: i'm doing something similar but the app get stuck when I press on "Send" to send the email. It just doesn't send.. anyone got this problem?